# OpenZeppelin - deploy crowdsale from Remix - wallet address

Tags: remix, crowdsale, openzeppelin

I am deploying a basic crowdsale using:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v1.6.0/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol";
```

I have no idea which address to deploy as a wallet, as below.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the comment in the contract, `wallet` is just an address where all the received fund will be transferred.

> ```
> /**
>  * @title Crowdsale
>  * @dev Crowdsale is a base contract for managing a token crowdsale.
>  * Crowdsales have a start and end timestamps, where investors can make
>  * token purchases and the crowdsale will assign them tokens based
>  * on a token per ETH rate. Funds collected are forwarded to a wallet
>  * as they arrive.
>  */
> ```

[source](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v1.6.0/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol#L7)

Comment: how does one generate a wallet address?

Comment: A wallet can be an external owned account (EOA) address or a smart contract address (gnosis-safe, argent, ...).